# Not navigating back to list after pressing Create Button

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-router-flux

My code is [here](https://github.com/samrao2/manager-4)

I am taking this [course](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/learn/v4/questions)

I added an action to navigate back to the employee list after hitting the create button but i am not navigating back. Can you help me understand what i might be doing wrong?

Here is the action creator file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import Actions from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {
  EMPLOYEE_UPDATE,
  EMPLOYEE_CREATE
} from './types';

export const employeeUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
    return {
      type: EMPLOYEE_UPDATE,
      payload: { prop, value }
    };
};

export const employeeCreate = ({ name, phone, shift }) => {
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
      .push({ name, phone, shift })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: EMPLOYEE_CREATE });
        Actions.employeeList({ type: 'reset' });
      });
  };
};
```

This is the screen i am not navigating away from:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work:

Router.js:

```
 const RouterComponent = () => {
    return (
       <Router sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 0 }}>
       <Stack key="root" hideNavBar="true" >
         <Scene key="auth">
            <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
       </Scene>

       <Scene key="main">
         <Scene
           key="employeeList"
           onRight={() => Actions.employeeCreate()}
           rightTitle="Add"
           component={EmployeeList}
           title="Employees List"
           initial
        />
      <Scene key="employeeCreate" component={EmployeeCreate} 
           title="Create Employee" />
      <Scene key="employeeEdit" component={EmployeeEdit} title="Edit 
         Employee" />
    </Scene>
  </Stack>
</Router>
 );
};
```

EmployeeActions.js:

```
 export const employeeCreate = ({ name, phone, shift }) => {
   const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

 return (dispatch) => {
   firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
    .push({ name, phone, shift })
    .then(() => {
       dispatch({ type: EMPLOYEE_CREATE });
       Actions.main({ type: 'reset' });
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: This worked! just changing Actions.employeeCreate to Actions.Main() worked. But my question is, why??? LOL Really appreciate you looking into this Jared. You are a gentleman and a scholar, sir!

Comment: Because you have to tell react-native-router-flux which routing 'bin' (if you will) to go to.  You have two bins: auth and main.  You could also do Actions.main.employeeList().  Sending it to main goes to employeeList by default because 1. It's the first scene listed in main.  2. It has the prop 'initial' designating it as the initial scene in that bin.  If you want to navigate to another scene in main that's not employeeList, you have to designate Actions.main.whateverYourKeyForThatComponentIs()

Comment: i did try Actions.main.employeeList() and the app does not do navigate away, but i dont get an error either. I think what is working is that the router is recognizing the "main" scene and taking me there, and since employeeList is the first or initial scene, that's where i end up...:)

Comment: Thinking of giving react-navigate a try.

Comment: Weird...I tried both ways with your code yesterday and they both worked.  This stuff can get aggravating...

Comment: Hmmm.. so what is different between my IDE and your IDE...therein lies the answer...:) Thanks!